# Calling prototype methods from within callback

Tags: javascript

I am creating a wrapper,  mock sample as follows

```
var car = function() { 
}

car.prototype.method1 =  function() {
    this.method2();
}

car.protoptype.method2 = function(callback) {
   var request =  foo() //call to async method

   request.onsucces  = function() {
       this.method3();
   });
}

car.protoptype.method3 = function(callback) {
    this.method4(); //not found
}

car.protoptype.method4 = function(callback) {
     //code
}
```

//caller

```
var vehicle = new Car;
vehicle.method1()
```

My issue is that method 4 isn't called. As its nested in the onsuccess callback, would the 'this' not scope to the object in method 4?

Comment: `request.onsucces{this.method3()}` <-- this is an invalid syntax

Comment: thanks, have corrected.

Comment: @Brian: Don't fix people's syntax like that. You don't know what the correct syntax should look like.

Comment: @user2736012 I disagree.  I feel it's not worth people focusing on the details to what was pretty clearly meant.  That's my position.  You clearly disagree and I respect/understand your position.

Comment: @BrianGenisio: The problem is that what you feel was clearly meant was apparently *not* what was meant, as OP had to correct your edit *(though the closing `)` was left)*.

Comment: @user2736021 I respect/understand your position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will want [`fn.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
request.onsuccess = this.method3.bind(this);
```

This way you can avoid any `var that = this;` context hacks

**Note** this relies on ECMAScript 5 and will not work in dinosaur browsers. If you need to support prehistoric software, look into [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

Comment: Your onsuccess assignment doesn't match the OPs signature.

Comment: @dc5: Another user had temporarily changed the question to make `onsuccess` look like a function call instead of an assignment.

Comment: @naomik - I have no idea how the OP's software is written and neither do you.  You are making an assumption.  I suggest you stop making those.

Comment: @dc5, I responded according to the way the question was written. I edited after the question was edited. Really, that's the best I can do.

Comment: @naomik Fair enough.  Hopefully you would grant me the same courtesy as I also commented according to what I saw in the question at the time.  Things  can change quickly here.  Best we can do is graciously accept feedback.

Comment: @dc5 I did extend you the courtesy of removing any comment directed toward your downvote.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion caused by my editing :(, was writing freehand and trying to mock a basic against my code. Trying the bind now (only need to support modern browsers)

Comment: @naomik - This: "I suggest you read up on function binding." is not courteous.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the `context` from within the callback.  You can store a reference to `this` as `self`:

```
car.protoptype.method2 = function(callback) {
   var self = this;
   var request =  foo() //call to async method

   request.onsucces(function() {
       self.method3()
   });
}
```

Others have suggested that you use `Function.prototype.bind`.  The problem with this approach is that it doesn't work in old browsers (<= IE8).  You can always [polyfill this behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) if you prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Function.prototype.bind()`

```
request.onsuccess = this.method3.bind(this);
```

This creates a new function with the value you passed as the first argument bound as the `this` value.